# After installing QT dependencies for KDE Connect now Ubuntu 22.04 won't boot

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 22.04, qt5, kde-connect

KDE SMS kept crashing for a week. I went into Discovery and looked at the installed program and saw unmet dependencies: qt??? (2 files were missing & they were version 5.X; don't remember exact name but the 2nd one had "quick" in it).

Came back to computer and it was showing a large onscreen keyboard. I hit escape and was shown a "never-before-seen" login screen with my actual name, not the name I have always used with Ubuntu. So I tried to type in my password with usb keyboard and nothing ever happened, no errors/messages. Rebooted and saw some errors like "can't read symbol" and more that I caught on a video but don't remember all. But again, it showed the Kubuntu splash screen and went to onscreen keyboard. If I type anything with that keyboard, after 3 strokes, computer freezes.

I can't believe that installing additional dependencies would break my OS as I did see during the update in terminal that some qt files went from older to newer versions. However, I am now using a live usb to be able to even use the computer and try to get help with how to fix this. I do not have grub as Linux is my only OS.

Anything I need to provide, please tell me what and how to find it and I will provide it. Not sure how to upload video but do have it for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The qt packages you installed likely forced some other dependencies of theirs to get updated. The qt libraries getting updated likely broke compatibility between various important packages, and therefore made the entire system unstable. You can try to `chroot` into your original installation from the USB drive, and run `apt install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop`. This will install all of the packages that came with Kubuntu by default, so if you removed some programs earlier you may have to do so again.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention and might be better is I do use timeshift and have daily snapshots; I found them on my hard drive. Have never done it before, but if i restore yesterday's snapshot will that fix this? Thanks

Comment: @myviolinsings restoring a snapshot from before when the issue occurred should fix it. That's what backups are for ;)

Comment: Thanks. Thank God I set that up last week.  :)